# YouTube channel has no default live broadcast

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

A small percentage of our users don't seem to have a default live broadcast on YouTube even though live streaming is enabled on their channel.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
youtube.liveBroadcasts
.list({
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails,status',
    mine: true,
    broadcastType: 'persistent',
})
```

Here's a normal response:

```
{ kind: 'youtube#liveBroadcastListResponse',
  etag: '"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/tnMgqhFvImsLcGAkkJ86gMVeu7o"',
  pageInfo: { totalResults: 0, resultsPerPage: 5 },
  items:
   [ { kind: 'youtube#liveBroadcast',
       etag: '"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/FqKww8uAZT-v7cY4LAc70S74LZE"',
       id: 'jW9y9FCovHs',
       snippet: [Object],
       status: [Object],
       contentDetails: [Object] } ] }
```

But for some channels, it returns an item with no data:

```
{ kind: 'youtube#liveBroadcastListResponse',
  etag: '"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/6A_Pgj2FJo4w0Hg6io_OE8jCrzY"',
  pageInfo: { totalResults: 0, resultsPerPage: 5 },
  items:
   [ { kind: 'youtube#liveBroadcast',
       etag: '"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"' } ] }
```

These users will often have other past live broadcast, but no default.

The [snippet.isDefaultBroadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.isDefaultBroadcast) section in the docs says that each channel with live streaming enabled should have a default broadcast. Any ideas? Is there something different about certain channels that would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation about [how default broadcast work](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.isDefaultBroadcast). It says that when a channel starts streaming video to its default stream, the video is visible on the channel's default broadcast. When the stream ends, YouTube converts the completed broadcast to a YouTube video and assigns the video a YouTube video ID. I think this will only modify by the owner of the channel.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I can't start streaming to the default stream because there is no default stream. In addition to not having a default live broadcast, they also don't appear to have a default live stream object. Without the stream object, I can't construct an RTMP url to start streaming.